# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object- Possible Babel Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

[image]

Everything in my project was working until randomly everything crashed upon launch. I am guessing that this has something to do with babel because it was working on second and now it isn't. As you can see the error persists throughout different parts of my application.

Something to note is it says "check the render method of 'SceneView'", but I do not have a SceneView.

I was getting this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'regeneratorRuntime.mark'), until I decided to switch from npm to yarn and now I am getting the error you are currently seeing.

[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "roam",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "jest-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.6.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.49.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-pages": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-persist-sensitive-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.14",
    "util": "*"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", {"modules": false}], "react-native"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env", {"modules": false}], "react-native"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like an import/export problem. Instead of images, please copy and paste the errors here. Also, can we see your `SceneView` component?

Comment: @devserkan. That is the thing, I do not have a SceneView.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that explanation in your question. But, this is weird. Is there a possibility to use `SceneView` name and call it somewhere in your component? The warnings in your second image are not related this issue.

Comment: In atom I did a global search for sceneview and nothing came up. I do not believe I am using it at all.

Comment: After doing some digging it appears sceneview has to do with expo, which I am no longer using in my application.

Comment: Can this `SceneView` be related React Native?

Comment: I'm not experienced with React Native, but if you are not using it then try to remove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177443/discussion-between-christian-lessard-and-devserkan).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug by downgrading react dependency.